# Products tabs not showing in a woocommerc single product page which is designed by elemntor

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem about single product page. I designed a template for this in projekts (woodmart template). now description for tabs of products element not showing in the product's pages.

i have deactivated all of plugins and that does not worked

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have defined the "Tabs" element in Layouts -> Single product layout. https://take.ms/HVFjS
2. Make sure that the product has the description